# CloudFormation CloudWatch Cron Not Linking?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to link my CloudWatch Rule to a Lambda target. But it appears that it does not work

```
CronPullQuotationFromActuary:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  Properties:
    ...
CronPullQuotationFromActuaryEvent:
  Type: AWS::Events::Rule
  Properties:
    ScheduleExpression: cron(5 0/1 * * ? *) # Run every hour at 5 minute
    State: ENABLED
    Targets:
      - Arn: !GetAtt CronPullQuotationFromActuary.Arn
        Id: !Ref CronPullQuotationFromActuary
```

Even though the CloudWatch dashboard looks fine

[image]

The lambda is not

[image]

Notice no triggers. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be missing a [Lambda Permission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html) for CloudWatch Events.

Based on **To create a rule using the AWS CLI** [Schedule AWS Lambda Functions Using CloudWatch Events: Create a Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html#schedule-create-rule), you would want the following permission:

```
Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
Properties: 
  Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
  FunctionName: <Your Function Name>
  Principal: events.amazonaws.com
  SourceArn: !GetAtt CronPullQuotationFromActuaryEvent.Arn
```